# downloading waypoint layer from garmin gps 60CSx to QGIS 1.8.0Lisboa

Tags: qgis, garmin

I want to download waypoint from my Garmin GPS but it responded

> the layer GPS.gpx?type=waypoint is not a valid layer and can not be
>   added to the map

whereas my colleagues do the same without a problem.

Comment: try this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25761/why-wont-qgis-recognize-my-gps