# How to send GPX file to a GPS device

Tags: qgis-2, gpsbabel, gpstools

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 and want to send a GPX file to a GPS device, Garmin Astro 320.

When using the GPS Tool in QGIS and click the OK button I get the message

> Can not start GPSBabel!

What's wrong?

Comment: You might need to switch `%babel` for the actual path of the program. See the here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25761/why-wont-qgis-recognize-my-gps#comment35804_25765